# How to substitute all the vector(s) in a list of lists with a corresponding list?

Tags: r, dataframe

Preface: I'm not familiar with for loops on R.

The `gmt` variable contains lists of lists of character vectors. My goal is to substitute the name for each list in gmt (i.e., names(gmt))with its corresponding id. Everything before the first occurrence of `_` should be removed in the process.

```
for (i in gmt){
  as.data.frame(i)$name <- sub(".*?_", "", as.data.frame(i)$id)
}
```

Traceback:

```
Error in as.data.frame(i) <- `*vtmp*` : 
  could not find function "as.data.frame<-"
```

Data:

```
> dput(gmt)
structure(list(REACTOME_INTERLEUKIN_6_SIGNALING = list(id = "REACTOME_INTERLEUKIN_6_SIGNALING", 
    name = "http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/REACTOME_INTERLEUKIN_6_SIGNALING", 
    genes = c("JAK2", "TYK2", "CBL", "STAT1", "IL6ST", "IL6", 
    "IL6R", "JAK1", "STAT3", "PTPN11", "SOCS3")), REACTOME_APOPTOSIS = list(
    id = "REACTOME_APOPTOSIS", name = "http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/REACTOME_APOPTOSIS", 
    genes = c("BAD", "CFLAR", "PSMB1", "PSMC4", "BID", "VIM", 
    "FAS", "BAK1", "DAPK2", "CDH1", "PSMA4", "DSG2", "CASP8", 
    "PRKCQ", "ROCK1", "PSME4", "ARHGAP10", "TP63", "TP73", "PKP1", 
    "BAX", "PSMC5", "ADD1", "DNM1L", "PPP1R13B", "DYNLL1", "PSME1", 
    "CLSPN", "PSMD5", "DSP", "PSMD8", "MAPK1", "GZMB", "PSMC6", 
    "PSMA3", "PSMC1", "PSMB5", "ACIN1", "PSMA6", "PSME2", "PSMA7", 
    "E2F1", "PSMD10", "XIAP", "BMX", "STK24", "TRADD", "MAPK3", 
    "PSMD7", "TJP1", "BMF", "GSDMD", "TNFRSF10A", "AKT2", "BBC3", 
    "CARD8", "GSDME", "PSMA2", "MAPK8", "UNC5B", "PSMD3", "SEPTIN4", 
    "KPNB1", "C1QBP", "PSMD11", "YWHAE", "BIRC2", "PSMD9", "LMNB1", 
    "UNC5A", "KPNA1", "TFDP2", "PSMD14", "AKT3", "FASLG", "TJP2", 
    "APAF1", "TNFRSF10B", "PPP3CC", "TNFSF10", "H1-3", "H1-1", 
    "PSMF1", "PSMB2", "TRAF2", "TICAM1", "SEM1", "YWHAH", "PSMA1", 
    "PSME3", "CASP9", "YWHAQ", "STK26", "DSG3", "DSG1", "APC", 
    "DBNL", "NMT1", "TLR4", "PSMB7", "RIPK1", "UACA", "CASP6", 
    "TP53", "PMAIP1", "AKT1", "PSMB6", "PSMA5", "TP53BP2", "RPS27A", 
    "CDKN2A", "GSN", "GAS2", "APIP", "UBC", "BCL2L11", "LY96", 
    "PSMA8", "APPL1", "PSMD4", "PSMB4", "DFFA", "LMNA", "PSMC2", 
    "OMA1", "PSMD6", "PRKCD", "HMGB2", "CASP3", "YWHAZ", "CASP7", 
    "PSMC3", "YWHAB", "DAPK3", "CTNNB1", "FADD", "H1-4", "FNTA", 
    "STAT3", "PTK2", "DFFB", "AVEN", "YWHAG", "UBB", "CD14", 
    "BCL2L1", "BCL2", "CYCS", "PSMD1", "PSMD2", "SFN", "PLEC", 
    "MAGED1", "PAK2", "SATB1", "DIABLO", "H1-5", "PSMD13", "BCAP31", 
    "MAPT", "DCC", "H1-2", "H1-0", "HMGB1", "DAPK1", "PSMD12", 
    "SPTAN1", "OCLN", "TFDP1", "OPA1", "PSMB8", "PSMB10", "PPP3R1", 
    "UBA52", "PSMB11", "PSMB9", "TICAM2", "DYNLL2", "PSMB3")), 
    REACTOME_HEMOSTASIS = list(id = "REACTOME_HEMOSTASIS", name = "http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/REACTOME_HEMOSTASIS", 
        genes = c("FGR", "CD99", "TFPI", "KDM1A", "PRKAR2B", 
        "ITGAL", "ITGA3", "LAMP2", "ITGA2B", "TBXA2R", "NOS2", 
        "SELE", "CD9", "FYN", "PLAUR", "EHD3", "IGF1", "CD74", 
        "HGF", "SLC7A9", "EHD2", "CD44", "PRKCH", "VCL", "RAB27B", 
        "LCP2", "HSPA5", "BCAR1", "PIK3CB", "KIF1B", "ITIH4", 
        "F7", "ATP2B4", "DGKG", "GNA15", "GUCY1B1", "GPC1", "HMG20B", 
        "GNAI3", "DGKA", "PRKCQ", "PPP2R5A", "CD84", "KIF26A", 
        "RHOA", "PRKCZ", "ATP2B3", "KIF2A", "RASGRP2", "PPP2R5B", 
        "TRPC7", "ATP1B3", "GNB5", "CDC42", "ATP2B1", "WDR1", 
        "PRKACA", "SPP2", "ACTN1", "IRAG1", "ATP2A3", "MGLL", 
        "SRI", "ACTB", "TUBA3D", "KIFAP3", "STXBP2", "DGKD", 
        "APBB1IP", "ACTN2", "CAPZB", "PPP2R5C", "GNB1", "RAPGEF3", 
        "CEACAM1", "KIF22", "CARMIL1", "P2RX5", "APLP2", "APOB", 
        "KIF3C", "CEACAM6", "GNAS", "GP6", "GNA11", "DOCK9", 
        "DOCK3", "KIF9", "F11", "SIRPG", "P2RX7", "KIF16B", "NOS1", 
        "RCOR1", "THPO", "GLG1", "KIF4A", "ITGA6", "RAPGEF4", 
        "TF", "APOH", "ANGPT2", "SLC7A8", "TGFB2", "CBX5", "BRPF3", 
        "ITPR3", "JAK2", "ABL1", "SERPIND1", "P2RX6", "PPIL2", 
        "MAPK1", "PICK1", "SLC16A8", "TIMP3", "PDGFB", "VTI1B", 
        "ITPK1", "SERPINA4", "SLC8A3", "ABHD12", "PROCR", "TUBB1", 
        "ANGPT4", "KIF3B", "F9", "GATA1", "CD99L2", "TIMP1", 
        "MAGED2", "SYTL4", "DGKH", "MAPK3", "SLC7A6", "SLC7A5", 
        "STX4", "CSK", "SCG3", "PLAT", "TNFRSF10A", "PPP2CB", 
        "TUBB4A", "KLC3", "TGFB1", "CEACAM5", "PPP2R1A", "PIK3R2", 
        "MAG", "PIK3CG", "CAV1", "SERPINE1", "RARRES2", "CDC37L1", 
        "DOCK8", "GATA3", "RAD51C", "P2RX1", "PFN1", "C1QBP", 
        "AKAP10", "LGALS3BP", "COL1A1", "PRKAR1A", "PF4V1", "P2RX3", 
        "EHD1", "VWF", "SELPLG", "SH2B3", "GNB3", "PTPN6", "MAPK14", 
        "PHACTR2", "PDE10A", "PPP2R5D", "VEGFA", "KIF20A", "SPARC", 
        "PPP2CA", "KNG1", "HRG", "PRKAR2A", "GNAI2", "GNB4", 
        "ITGA4", "PDE1A", "GRB14", "FN1", "PROC", "SDC1", "SOS1", 
        "PLEK", "QSOX1", "STXBP3", "RAP1A", "HDAC1", "CAPZA1", 
        "DOCK7", "MFN2", "PLA2G4A", "CD58", "CD2", "KIF21B", 
        "CD48", "MPL", "PIK3R3", "F3", "SERPINC1", "APOA1", "SLC8A2", 
        "MYB", "TGFB3", "EPCAM", "GNA13", "TEK", "IFNA6", "IFNA8", 
        "CLU", "TNFRSF10B", "AKAP1", "A1BG", "KIF18A", "PIK3CA", 
        "PLG", "CD244", "PLAU", "SRGN", "ITPR2", "PDE1B", "CDK2", 
        "NFE2", "TUBA1B", "SDC4", "PLCG1", "PSG8", "CEACAM8", 
        "F13A1", "SERPINB6", "TREM1", "ABCC4", "KIF25", "IRF1", 
        "KLC1", "F10", "PRKCG", "RAP1B", "F2RL3", "GNG13", "TUBA4A", 
        "AAMP", "GNG11", "GNGT1", "GNAI1", "VPREB3", "IGLL1", 
        "RAC2", "DOCK4", "CALU", "PDE11A", "ISLR", "ATP1B2", 
        "KIF1C", "DOCK6", "KIF1A", "ACTN4", "GATA5", "SLC7A10", 
        "HABP4", "F12", "CAP1", "RBSN", "KIF3A", "RAF1", "JCHAIN", 
        "H3-3B", "KRAS", "VAV3", "CABLES1", "DOCK2", "DAGLA", 
        "P2RX4", "CD36", "PHF21A", "CD63", "MICAL1", "KCNMB4", 
        "DOCK10", "SERPINE2", "RAC1", "DGKB", "GATA4", "VPS45", 
        "GYPC", "KIF12", "TLN1", "IFNA21", "KLC4", "TUBB2A", 
        "TUBB2B", "ARRB1", "PRCP", "TRPC6", "PPP2R1B", "THBS1", 
        "KIF23", "KIF11", "KIF20B", "OLA1", "ITGAV", "PRKG2", 
        "MMRN1", "PDE5A", "TRPC3", "CENPE", "EGF", "KIF21A", 
        "ITGAX", "PDPK1", "KIF2B", "GATA6", "ARRB2", "PIK3R5", 
        "TP53", "SLC16A3", "GRB7", "VAV1", "SOD1", "APP", "AKT1", 
        "PRKACB", "KIF2C", "ITGA10", "ATP1B1", "F13B", "ECM1", 
        "SCCPDH", "LEFTY2", "RHOB", "RAB5A", "MANF", "AHSG", 
        "DGKQ", "PIK3R1", "LHFPL2", "PCYOX1L", "KCNMB1", "GNA12", 
        "DOCK11", "DOK2", "DOCK5", "AK3", "IFNA5", "IFNA16", 
        "DGKZ", "SERPING1", "ENDOD1", "ESAM", "CABLES2", "FERMT3", 
        "ALDOA", "ITGB1", "ADRA2A", "VEGFC", "DOCK1", "ITPR1", 
        "SLC7A11", "TUBA3E", "GUCY1A2", "MERTK", "CYRIB", "DGKE", 
        "PPP2R5E", "ANGPT1", "PRKCA", "CXADR", "JAM2", "APOOL", 
        "SLC16A1", "SLC7A7", "TTN", "KIF5A", "GNA14", "GNAQ", 
        "KCNMA1", "TSPAN7", "CD109", "ATP2B2", "LRP8", "DGKI", 
        "PAFAH2", "TAGLN2", "F11R", "FCER1G", "CYB5R1", "PTGIR", 
        "PDE9A", "ITGB2", "VAV2", "JAML", "SHC1", "ORAI2", "SH2B2", 
        "ITGA5", "RACGAP1", "GNG3", "ITIH3", "PDPN", "SDC3", 
        "KIF26B", "FCAMR", "H3-3A", "ALB", "ABHD6", "PPBP", "PF4", 
        "KIF15", "CLEC3B", "PRKCD", "TEX264", "ANXA5", "GUCY1A1", 
        "ITGA2", "F2RL2", "KLKB1", "DAGLB", "KIF6", "COL1A2", 
        "NOS3", "CDK5", "YWHAZ", "SYK", "PRKACG", "KIF27", "VEGFD", 
        "CLEC1B", "JAM3", "SERPINB8", "TMX3", "WEE1", "PRKCB", 
        "GNGT2", "CRK", "IGF2", "STIM1", "GNG8", "TUBA1A", "TUBA1C", 
        "KIFC2", "SERPINF2", "SLC3A2", "GNG4", "IRF2", "INPP5D", 
        "P2RY12", "SIN3A", "PTK2", "SDC2", "VPREB1", "GP9", "PCDH7", 
        "P2RY1", "ITGAM", "ZFPM2", "GYPA", "KIF5B", "PSG6", "CEACAM3", 
        "MFN1", "KCNMB3", "PRKCE", "FGG", "FGA", "FGB", "IFNB1", 
        "JMJD1C", "BSG", "GNB2", "GNG12", "GTPBP2", "CTSW", "RASGRP1", 
        "CFL1", "TUBB8B", "OLR1", "VEGFB", "TNFRSF10D", "GNG5", 
        "SELP", "ATP2A2", "HRAS", "KLC2", "A2M", "TUBB6", "YES1", 
        "GNG7", "RHOG", "CHID1", "GRB2", "SH2B1", "TUBAL3", "THBD", 
        "GP5", "PTPN11", "GATA2", "ZFPM1", "F2", "F2R", "RAD51B", 
        "ANXA2", "LCK", "SLC8A1", "GAS6", "H3C13", "PSG9", "TUBA8", 
        "ADRA2C", "PROS1", "F8", "MAFF", "GP1BA", "PRKG1", "KIF18B", 
        "GNG2", "PDE2A", "IFNA10", "P2RX2", "PRKAR1B", "TUBB4B", 
        "IFNA2", "SELL", "SERPINA5", "SERPINA3", "KIF19", "PPIA", 
        "ATP2A1", "PTPN1", "PRTN3", "HBG2", "HDAC2", "MMP1", 
        "CD47", "NHLRC2", "FLNA", "FAM3C", "MAFG", "SRC", "H3C12", 
        "SERPINA1", "H3C4", "PDGFA", "SPN", "KCNMB2", "SERPINB2", 
        "PSAP", "S100A10", "CFD", "KIF13B", "IFNA1", "PLCG2", 
        "TUBA3C", "SIRPA", "TOR4A", "MAFK", "CALM1", "F5", "CAPZA2", 
        "L1CAM", "GP1BB", "H3C14", "H3C15", "KIFC1", "MPIG6B", 
        "LY6G6F", "CD177", "PSG5", "TMSB4X", "IGKV4-1", "IGKV5-2", 
        "IGKV3D-20", "IGLV6-57", "IGLV1-51", "IGLV1-47", "IGLV1-44", 
        "IGLV7-43", "IGLV1-40", "IGLV3-27", "IGLV3-25", "IGLV2-23", 
        "IGLV3-21", "IGLV3-19", "IGLV2-14", "IGLV2-11", "IGLV3-1", 
        "IGLC2", "IGLC3", "IGHA2", "IGHA1", "IGHM", "IGHV1-2", 
        "IGHV2-5", "IGHV3-7", "IGHV3-11", "IGHV3-13", "IGHV3-23", 
        "IGHV3-33", "IGHV4-34", "IGHV4-39", "IGHV1-46", "IGHV3-48", 
        "IGHV3-53", "IGHV1-69", "NRAS", "LAT", "HBE1", "HBG1", 
        "ITGA1", "IFNA7", "GNAT3", "PSG3", "PSG7", "HBD", "IGHV4-59", 
        "KIF4B", "IFNA14", "ORM2", "ORM1", "PSG1", "IFNA13", 
        "IFNA17", "IFNA4", "IGKV2D-30", "IGKV3-20", "IGKV1D-33", 
        "IGKV1-17", "IGKV1-16", "MIF", "IGKV1D-16", "IGKV3-11", 
        "IGKV1-33", "PSG2", "IGKV1-39", "IGKV2D-28", "GNG10", 
        "PSG11", "PSG4", "IGKV2-30", "IGKV1-12", "IGKV1-5", "TUBA4B", 
        "IGKV2-28", "IGKV3-15", "HBB", "GYPB", "SELENOP", "IGKV2D-40", 
        "IGKV1D-39", "LYN", "TUBB3", "ITGB3", "PECAM1", "TUBB8", 
        "IGHV3-30", "H3C8", "ADRA2B", "IGHV2-70", "DGKK", "H3C6", 
        "H3C11", "H3C1", "ORAI1", "PIK3R6", "H3C7", "IGLV2-8", 
        "H3C10", "IGKV1D-12", "H3C2", "H3C3")), REACTOME_INTRINSIC_PATHWAY_FOR_APOPTOSIS = list(
        id = "REACTOME_INTRINSIC_PATHWAY_FOR_APOPTOSIS", name = "http://www.gsea-msigdb.org/gsea/msigdb/human/geneset/REACTOME_INTRINSIC_PATHWAY_FOR_APOPTOSIS", 
        genes = c("BAD", "BID", "BAK1", "CASP8", "TP63", "TP73", 
        "BAX", "PPP1R13B", "DYNLL1", "MAPK1", "GZMB", "E2F1", 
        "XIAP", "MAPK3", "BMF", "GSDMD", "AKT2", "BBC3", "CARD8", 
        "GSDME", "MAPK8", "SEPTIN4", "C1QBP", "YWHAE", "TFDP2", 
        "AKT3", "APAF1", "PPP3CC", "YWHAH", "CASP9", "YWHAQ", 
        "NMT1", "UACA", "TP53", "PMAIP1", "AKT1", "TP53BP2", 
        "CDKN2A", "APIP", "BCL2L11", "CASP3", "YWHAZ", "CASP7", 
        "YWHAB", "STAT3", "AVEN", "YWHAG", "BCL2L1", "BCL2", 
        "CYCS", "SFN", "DIABLO", "TFDP1", "PPP3R1", "DYNLL2"))), class = "GMT")
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, we can extract the `id` and use `setNames`

```
gmt <- setNames(gmt, sub("^[^_]+_", "", sapply(gmt, `[[`, "id")))
```

Or if we want to replace the `name` component

```
gmt <- Map(\(x, y) {x$name <- y; x}, gmt, 
    sub("^[^_]+_", "",sapply(gmt, `[[`, "id")))
```

Or using `lapply`

```
gmt <- lapply(gmt, \(x) {x$name <- sub("^[^_]+_", "", x$id); x})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I replace all the `name` character variable with the corresponding output from `setNames(gmt, sub("^[^_]+_", "", sapply(gmt, `[[`, "id")))`?

Comment: @melolili Do you want to replace the url with this value or just the suffix part

Comment: I want to replace the url with the output from `setNames(gmt, sub("^[^_]+_", "", sapply(gmt, [[, "id")))`

Comment: Thank you, but I need to retain it in a GMT format. Your code coerces the output into a list.

Comment: @melolili your original data is already in a nested list